# Harry Dresden Item Descriptions

Tags: the-dresden-files, jim-butcher

I am working on creating a Harry Dresden costume.  As such, I need the descriptions from the series for the following items (I can't find them):

- Silver rings
- Blasting Rod
- Staff
- Shield Bracelet
- Bob's Skull (I think it's just a basic skull, not sure though)

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but if you want visual representations, you can probably find screengrabs from the TV series.

Comment: @forceflow his attire in the tv show is almost completely different than in the books.

Comment: I would love to see the costume when it's put together! Can you post a photo?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In *Grave Peril*, the silver **ring** is described as "a plain silver ring, its interior surface inscribed with a number of runes", worn on the right hand.  By *Small Favor*, Harry has upgraded -- "there was one of them on each finger, a band made of three rings woven into a braid."

*Small Favor* describes the **blasting rod** as "a simple wooden rod, a couple of feet long, heavily carved with sigils and runes".

The **staff** is described as "heavy", "carved wood" and a "solid length of oak".  It's quite long, judging by this:

> Luccio sat beside Gard with her slender staff and her silver rapier resting on the floorboards between her feet, though my own staff was a lot longer and had to slant back between the front seats and past Gard’s head, up into the rear window well.

It's possibly also carved with runes--

> his right hand he carried a wooden staff carved with runes that looked almost precisely like my own

-- and, although *Storm Front* refers to it as "pale, smooth wood", *Blood Rites* says "I focused it on my staff, and the sigils and runes carved along its surface became suddenly suffused with eye-searing scarlet light."

In *Grave Peril*, both wand and blasting rod are described as "freshly carved and still a little green around the edges".

**ETA**: as per Joakim Elofsson's comment, *Ghost Story* has the staff as "six feet of oak" with "[r]unes and sigils carved in a tight spiral down the length".

In *Storm Front*, the shield **bracelet** is described as a "bracelet of tiny
medieval-style shields" and "bracelet of silver shields"; that one is destroyed and replaced.  In *Death Masks* it's "a silver bracelet dangling a dozen tiny, medieval-style shields" but *Small Favor* describes the redesigned bracelet as "made of a braid of many metals, the chain of the bracelet was hung with multiple charms in the shape of medieval shields."

Bob's **skull** is described in *Storm Front* as a "bleached white human skull."  It's "a few hundred years" old.  When Bob is talking, "a pair of lights came up in the empty sockets of the skull, orangish, flickering like candle flames."  It has a bottom jaw - "his bony teeth rattled when his mouth clicked closed again."

Comment: is there a size reference for the blasting rod anywhere?

Comment: *Small Favor* has "a couple of feet long"?  There's also "a length of wood a little longer than my forearm, carved over with runes and sigils" in *Death Masks*.  In *Fool Moon*, it's heavy enough to be swung like a baseball bat, though that could just imply strong rather than thick.

Comment: _Ghost Story_ has "Runes and sigils carved in a tight spiral down the length of the **staff**. I took a deep breath and once more felt the solid power of my wizard's **staff**, six feet of oak as big around as my own circled thumb and finger, ..." ch40

Comment: Bob's Skull is also heavily covered with runes.  This is made more clear in later books, and mentioned extensively in *Skin Game*.  By this point, Harry also only has his staff remaining, but he's carved some **very** interesting runes into it.

Answer (score 1):

- The blasting rod is smaller than a baseball bat, or a sword/umbrella,
  as he can keep it in his coat pockets, and does not keep it in the
  trash can by the door next to his staff, umbrellas, and the Swords.
- The original force ring was a simple ring, but later he melded
  several together (either 3 or 5, I cannot rememeber).
- Bob's skull is mentioned to have binding runes inscribed, and is shown as such when
  you look at screencaps from the TV show, they did it justice.
- The staff is known to have been made of lightning-struck oak (He mentions this in passing to Ebeneezer in ... Cold Days?). I always assumed it was relatively formless, but when he has Lash riding shotgun, there are sigils that glow with hellfire on both the staff and blasting rod.
- I don't remember much about how he describes his shield braclet(s) but I do remember that what they had on TV was very wrong. It looked cool, but didn't match.
- His necklace has been reproduced by the internet ad nauseum, but they rarely include his mother's gemstone from the later books.

Comment: The mention of his staff being made of lightning struck oak is from several books, but the one your referring to is from Changes, when Eb arrives at Chichen Itza.